# grub-efi-amd64 setup failure on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. When I was updating my packages by running

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

I got this error:

```
Setting up grub-efi-amd64 (2.06-2ubuntu10) ...
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64 (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 | grub-pc; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not configured yet.
  Package grub-pc is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Trying to install `grub-pc` didn't help. Then I tried to purge my grub packages in order to reinstall them. I ran:

```
sudo apt-get purge grub\*
```

And got the same error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 shim-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed but it is not going to be installed or
                        grub-efi-arm64-signed but it is not installable
               Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.04-1ubuntu24) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?